# Laravel Eloquent Filter By Column of Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Using the Eloquent ORM I have my models set up like so: `Post` `belongsToMany` `Category`

Post.php

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'posts_categories');
}
```

I want to filter posts by a column of the categories relationship.

So I want to do something like:

```
$posts->where('categories.slug', '=', Input::get('category_slug'));
```

This doesn't work though.

I also tried:

```
$with['categories'] = function($query){ 
    $query->where('slug', '=', Input::get('category_slug'));
};

$posts::with($with)->get();
```

But I thnk that's for filtering the categories not filtering BY the category.

Can anyone show me the way?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I can't access my Vagrant box right now, but I believe this should work:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function($q)
{
    $q->where('slug', '=', Input::get('category_slug'));

})->get();
```

Comment: Works great! Had to upgrade to Laravel v4.1 though as this is a new feature

Comment: Thanks a ton. I’ve spend hours trying to figure this out and finally solved it! :O

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: whereHas does a full table scan. For small tables this is fine if say (categories) ha 100,000 rows then this will drastically be slow. How do you go about that then?

Comment: `whereHas` filters out the non-nelationship results. Any way to not filter the null relationship results?

Comment: @Dr.House to answer your question late (but hopefully useful for others) use `Post::whereHas('categories',...)->orWhereDoesntHave('categories')`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick way to filter on related model column:

```
$allConsultants = Consultant::whereHas('user', function($query)
{
    $query->where('is_approved', '=', 1);

})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (and the identical one 8 years newer, that inexplicably has upvotes) is correct. It selects the model based on whether its relationship contains certain values. However it will return all instances of that relationship, regardless of values.

So given a `Post` with three different categories 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz'; this code:

```php
$posts = Post::whereHas('categories', fn($q) => $q->where('slug', 'foo')
    ->get();
```

Will return the `Post` model with 3 `Category` models linked.

To select the parent model based on the relationship's values *and* only return the matching relationships, you need to call the same closure twice:

```php
$posts = Post::whereHas('categories', fn($q) => $q->where('slug', 'foo')
    ->with(['categories' => fn($q) => $q->where('slug', 'foo')])
    ->get();
```

`whereHas()` selects the parent model, `with()` selects the child models.