# Laravel eloquent relationship and view

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to show a structure using as example the tables showed in this thread:
[Laravel Eloquent Filter By Column of Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801859/laravel-eloquent-filter-by-column-of-relationship)

Using this I would like to show in one page (index.blade.php for example) something like this:

```
Category 1
    Post1.Category1
    Post2.Category1
Category 2
    Post1.Category2
    Post2.Category2
    Post3.Category2
    Post4.Category2
Category 3    
    Post1.Category3
```

I don't know what exactly which arrays to I need to pass from Controller.

I can get the list of Categories but how the post for each category???

Thanks

Any idea

Comment: rephrase you question and format the code so we know what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass in the Categories with their Posts.  It's pretty straightforward.

### Controller

```
$categories = Category::with('posts')->get();
return View::make('some.view')->with('categories', $categories);
```

### View

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    {{{ $category->name }}}
    @foreach($category->posts as $post)
        {{{ $post->name }}}.{{{ $category->name }}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```