# Get users with current role

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel to create a website and I have a problem with eloquent. I have a database scheme as following:

```
*****************           *****************
*   Users       *           *   User_roles  *
*****************           *****************
*   id          *I----+     *   id          *
*   name        *     +----K*   user_id     *
*   password    *           *   role_id     *
*****************           *   start_date  *
                            *   stop_date   *
                            *****************
```

All neede relationships have been made in the models, there is a one to many from the users to the roles, a user can have multiple roles at the same time.

I was wondering if someone can help me to get all users which are in role_id 3 on the current date using eloquent. I can't seem to be able to use the relationship or create a join.

**Update:**
I have now created the relationships between the tables and I am starting from the user_roles table.

This is the code in my models:

```
// User.php
public function user_roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('UserRole', 'user_id');   
}

// UserRole.php
public function user() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}
```

I was wondering how I can now filter the users when I start from the User_roles table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Zizaco Confide and Entrust, i love them :) 2 packages that are easy to install and use.

if im right for your current code:

```
//Class roles
public function getUsers(){
    return $this->hasMany('User');
}


//In the controller:
$role = Role::find(role_id_here);

foreach($role->getUsers AS $user){
    echo $user.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse! thank you for this, I was constantly thinking the other way around, starting from the users table. I will test this tonight and let you know if it works. :)

One question though, is it possible to put another filter on the users table this way?

Comment: Cant answer your question about the filter... Never used before but ill check the docs tomorow for ya

Comment: I have found the solution, I have to user `whereHas`. As found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801859/laravel-eloquent-filter-by-column-of-relationship