# Laravel HasMany with where condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two `tables`, `users` and products. Products table structure is:

| id | product_name | user_id | isGlobal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | banana | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | pear | 20 | 0 |
| 4 | melon | 30 | 0 |

Here is User model where made relation with products

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Controller which i'm getting products

```
$products = $user->product()->get();
```

Problem: Product with `isGlobal = 1` param must be shown for every user.

How can solve this?

---

PS: below solution did not work.

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class)->where('isGlobal', 1);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent Filter By Column of Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801859/laravel-eloquent-filter-by-column-of-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply your condition in 2 places:

- In `hasMany` Relation
- Eager loading conditions

So for first:

```php
public function products()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class)->where('isGlobal', 1);
}
```

this will work for conditions when you want to access the data this way:

```php
$products = $user->products;
```

But this won't work for eager loading situation like:

```php
$users = User::with('products')->get();
```

so you have to apply the condition on all of your eager loading situations like this:

```php
$users = User::with('products' => function($query) {
    $query->where('isGlobal', 1);
})->get();
```

Comment: return $this->hasMany(Product::class)->where('isGlobal', 1); this method is not works. I tested it.