# Laravel use WHERE with relation

Tags: laravel

I need to filter categories by name. Category name is stored in separated table `category_details`. When i listing this in blade all is good but when i need to filter it its show

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'details.name'
> in 'where clause'

**Controller method**

```
   public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $categories = Category::with('details')
            ->when($request->has('name'), function ($q) use ($request) {
                return $q->where('details.name', 'like', $request->query('name') .'%');
            })
            ->paginate(15);
        
       

           return view('ecommerce::admin.catalog.category.index', compact('categories'));
    }
```

**Here is model method**

```
 public function details()
 {
     return $this->hasOne(CategoryDetails::class, 'category_id', 'category_id');
 }
```

How can i achive this?

Comment: The column is definitely `name` yeah, and not something like `category_name`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent Filter By Column of Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801859/laravel-eloquent-filter-by-column-of-relationship)

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $categories = Category::with('details')
            ->when($request->has('name'), function ($q) use ($request) {
                return $q->whereHas('details', function ($query) use ($request) {
                    return $query->where('name', 'like', '%'. $request->query('name') .'%');
                });
            })
            ->paginate(15);

        $filter_categories = Category::with(['details', 'childrenRecursive'])->where('parent_id', '=', null)->get();

        return view('ecommerce::admin.catalog.category.index', compact('categories', 'filter_categories'));
    }
```

Comment: To explain a little, `with` doesn't do what a lot of people expect; it doesn't add a `JOIN` to the query. Instead, it runs another query *after* the main query, to fetch all the matching rows in the relationship. Thus, `details.name` isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a function for this.
You can simply use whereRelation. ([Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries))

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::with('details')
        ->whereRelation('details', 'name', 'like', $request->query('name') . '%')
        ->paginate(15);

    return view('ecommerce::admin.catalog.category.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

Comment: This is more simplest than my solution